# removing event listeners in Nuxt/Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm on Nuxtjs 2.13 and i wanna know "how should I remove event listeners (is there a need??)".

I'm not talkinkg about js `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` . I'm more curious about `this.$emit()` , `$nuxt.$emit()` and `$nuxt.$on()` . is there a way to remove `$nuxt.$on()` or listener on component `<mycomp @myevent="do()" />` in `beforeDestroy()` and is it necessary?

as my Nuxt project using so much RAM on my server, i kindda think there are some optimization needed.

Comment: I think Nuxt automatically remove all events that declared by "v-on" directive when the components un-mounted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#unmounted

> When this hook (unmounted - OP) is called, all directives of the component instance have been unbound, all event listeners have been removed, and all child component instance have also been unmounted.

However, there is `vm.$off` which can

> Remove custom event listener(s).
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off

I saw it used here in a Nuxt context to remove `$nuxt.$on` listeners:
https://medium.com/@aneesshameed/event-bus-in-nuxt-7728315e81b6

So, if need be, use `$nuxt.$off` to remove custom events in Nuxt.